# Designing globally available services using Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, failover, disaster-recovery, azure-traffic-manager

We are working with SQL Failover Groups and I came across [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-designing-cloud-solutions-for-disaster-recovery#feedback) suggesting that it is possible to build an architecture that maintains region integrity during failover using Traffic Manager and Failover Groups. The scenario I am interested in is Scenario 1, which has this accompanying diagram:

[image]

I am aware of other ways in which to achieve region integrity, but I am interested to understand how it is possible in this scenario. Can someone please clarify how the database region remains consistent with the web app region in Scenario 1? The diagram shows that both regions use the Read Write connection string of the failover group. My understanding is that when the database in Region A reports an issue, the web app in Region A, which is still connected to the DB in Region A via the Failover Group's primary RW connection, will report to traffic manager (TM) that there is a connectivity issue during TM's ping and therefore Region A is degraded.

TM will then direct traffic to Region B. However, Region B is using the RW failover group connection string and so it is dependent on the failover group switching to the DB in region B.

My confusion is this: once the failover group successfully switches to the database in Region B, i.e. the primary DB server is now Region B, what stops TM from switching back to the web app in Region A? Region A should now report back as online to TM due to a successful connection to the DB because the Failover Group has switched its primary, albeit to a database in Region B, but the web app is appropriately unaware of which region the database resides in because it is behind the Failover Group and so it should just report a succesful connection, therefore causing TM to direct traffic back to Region A, therefore leaving the architecture in a cross-region state, nullifying the purpose of the solution, i.e. to have all resources to run under a single region in the event of a failover and fail-back.

Can someone explain how region integrity is maintained here please?

## Update

After some digging around I found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auto-failover-group#failover-groups-and-network-security) which appears to complement [the other](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-designing-cloud-solutions-for-disaster-recovery#feedback). The article describes the problem from the perspective of VNET's where regional collocation is important. So in the example from the perspective of VNET's: if the DB in region A fails causing a failover to DB in region B, the RW node of the failover group becomes Region B causing Region A to fail - i.e. Region A cannot connect to Region B due to VNET rules; therefore the entire system fails over to Region B in its entirety and maintaining the RW node in both Region A and Region B apps, i.e. no separate database connection configuration required. This allows a full region failover when just the primary database fails. Here's the appropriate section from the article:

> Initiate manual failover when the outage is detected. This option is optimized for the applications that require consistent latency between the front-end and the data tier and supports recovery when either front end, data tier or both are impacted by the outage.

So as far as I can tell to achieve full failover of a region and maintain regional collocation of resources in the event that a database within a failover group fails, you must configure a VNET in addition to the components in the above diagram and the steps detailed in the [original article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-designing-cloud-solutions-for-disaster-recovery#feedback). Seems obvious, but it isn't clear from just reading that page. If there are other opinions please advise.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the right place for this question; it's for programming questions and this has nothing to do with that. One of the other Stack Exchange sites will be a better choice for this; possibly Server Fault (I'm not Registered there so I'm not sure if this would fit).

Comment: Perhaps the assumption is that a legitimate failure in Region A would bring down both the database and the web app in that region. If there was _just_ a database failure then neither the traffic manager nor the web apps should even notice as the database layer should fail over seamlessly. That's my theory.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid - that is a sound theory, but the article seems to suggest that resource collocation is maintained even when just a DB is unavailable. Unless I have misread it.